# Allow interface to implicitly convert to JsonData

Tags: typescript

Can I modify [this definition](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#more-recursive-type-aliases) of a Json data type to allow json-compatible types to implicity convert to it?

```
type JsonValue =
    | string
    | number
    | boolean
    | null
    | { [property: string]: JsonValue }
    | JsonValue[];
```

I have a type like below:

```
interface AttachedFile {
  id: string
  name: string
  size: number
  type: string
}
```

And I want an assignment to work:

```
const q : JsonValue = someAttachedFile
```

But I get the error      `Type 'AttachedFile' is not assignable to type '{ [property: string]: JsonValue; }'. Index signature is missing in type 'AttachedFile'.`

Answer (score 3):

JsonValue is not a JSON

```
type JsonValue =
    | string
    | number
    | boolean
    | null
    | { [property: string]: Json }
    | Json[];

interface JSON {
    readonly [Symbol.toStringTag]: string;
}
```

Your type is javascript object

```
interface AttachedFile {
  id: string
  name: string
  size: number
  type: string
}
```

To make json, you need to call,

```
const q = JSON.stringify(someAttachedFile)
```

Which will result in a **String!**

```
"{                       // now this is JsonValue
  id: "some id" // <------------------||||
  name: "some name" // <---------------|||
  size: 1 // <--------------------------||
  type: "some type" // <-----------------|
}"
```

So `JsonValue` is never used by developer, its used by Visual Studio Code to help working with JSON files (for example when you `require('data.json')`)

And the typescript doc uses JsonValue to demonstrate recursive types, which is easy to understand with JSON

All you can do is to convert json object to your AttachedFile

```
const q: AttachedFile = JSON.parse(someJsonString) // convert json string to AttachedFile
```

Comment: I'm talking about JavaScript data objects that are compatible with JSON, that is, they have been decoded from JSON and can be encoded as JSON.  Consider only the types I have in the question.